# Customize Sentry alert content

Tags: sentry

Sentry allows to define [alerts](https://docs.sentry.io/product/alerts/) when issues reach certain thresholds. The alerts that are delivered per Mail look like

```
New alert from <project> in <environment>

<Issue>

Exception
<stacktrace>

<additional information e.g. contexts>

Tags
<tags>
```

Now the stacktrace may contain sensitive data (e.g. e-mail addresses) that I do not want to share via mail. How can I remove stacktrace and additional information from the alert mail?

Answer (score 1):

Sentry calls it data scrubbing.

In your project's settings. Go to Security and Privacy, at the bottom of the page, you'll find Advanced Data Scrubbing. This is where you use can create rules that much your needs and will be removed/hashed/replaced/masked before the information gets to you. For more info : [Advanced Data Scrubbing](https://docs.sentry.io/product/data-management-settings/scrubbing/advanced-datascrubbing/)

Here's an example of a rule that removes the username of the user once an error occurs and the username of the user is part of the debugging file :

[image]

Comment: As I understand data scrubbing it also removes the information from the issue itself. Is there a way to keep it in the issue, but not transmit it via mail?

Comment: @Benjamin The only way you can do that is if you host your own Sentry client, you'll be able to modify the source code or create a logic that will do that. One other method would be to send to one email and you can create your own rules or create scripts that will clean up the confidential data and finally dispatch to others emails.